# Sails.JS: Configure policies depending on whether the app is running in Dev or Prod mode?

Tags: sails.js

I have a Sails.JS app that, when in production, requires authentication from users. However, when I'm developing the app locally, I would like to allow unrestricted view to all pages.

How do I configure the `policies.js` in such a way that it behaves differently depending on whether the app is running in development or production mode?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if your project involves multiple users in the production environment, disabling login for local development could cause problems with dynamically generated pages based on an actively logged in user and may ultimately complicate things further in the long run when switching back to a production environment & re-enabling login for multiple users.

If this is merely a hassle with needing to re-login on each `sails lift` you can alternatively [download & install redis](https://redis.io/), then run it locally in a separate terminal with `redis-server` and then use `sails lift --redis`. From here, the next logged in user for your sails project should remain logged in even if you kill and re-lift with `sails lift --redis` again - essentially getting rid of the need to login for the time being.  Hope this helps simplify and achieve what you are wanting to do!

Comment: I use this all the time -- if you need help installing redis initially, and you're on a mac, check out Homebrew